# MKMapView freezing when rendering custom annotations

Tags: swift, annotations, rendering, mapkit, freeze

There are approximately **1500 customized annotations** with values and images.

I understand that this customization has a high price to be rendered in real time, but the **UI is freezing(some time)** during the **viewfor annotation** (when the user moves the map, each annotation takes time to render and more it zooms out, more annotations appear and the longer the UI freezes).

In the same application on android, I managed to improve this by **clustering all the annotations out of sight, only rendering them when they became visible**, without freezing the map.

Rendering must occur in the background, outside the main thread.

Other suggestions are also welcome.

[image]

Some code: viewDidLoad()

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.register(CustomPinAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
// mapView.register(CustomPinAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        
        ... configureDatabase()
        ... loadMapMap()
        ... loadAnnotations()
    }
```

more code: viewfor annotation

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation.isMember(of: MKUserLocation.self) { return nil }
    if annotation is MKClusterAnnotation { return nil }
    
    guard let customAnnotation = annotation as? CustomPin else { return nil }
    
... GET ANNOTATION INFO ...

    let reusePin = preco+stared+fechado+excluido+publico+particular
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reusePin) as? CustomPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil { pinView = CustomPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reusePin) }
    else { return pinView }

... RENDER CUSTOM ANNOTATION IMAGE ...

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    pinView?.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: size.width / 5 , y: -size.height / 5)
    print("=", terminator:"")
    return pinView
}
```

CustomPinAnnotationView.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class CustomPinAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    private var observerContext = 0
    
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        clusteringIdentifier = "cluster"
        collisionMode = .circle
        centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -10) // Offset center point to animate better with marker annotations
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            removeObserverIfAny()
        }
        didSet {
            if let annotation = annotation as? CustomPin {
                annotation.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(CustomPin.subtitle), context: &observerContext)
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        removeObserverIfAny()
    }

    private func removeObserverIfAny() {
        if let oldAnnotation = annotation as? CustomPin {
            oldAnnotation.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(CustomPin.subtitle))
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        guard context == &observerContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your annotations are semi-transparent. Have you tried using an opaque image? I seem to remember (dimly) that calculating the transparency can be quite intensive.

Comment: I removed the shadows and alpha leaving the rendering of images with only solid colors and the rendering time improved a little (about 20%), but due to the large amount of annotations, when I zoom out and many annotations should appear, the map keeps freezing for a few seconds.

Comment: I have a map with up-to 2200 annotations. My old iPad struggles and freezes as you describe though my new iPhone handles it much better. Clustering gives only a small improvement for me.

Comment: if a reusable AnnotationView is not used at the moment, MapKit sets annotation to nil. You are setting an observer in the case of setting annotation to nil, which is probably a bug. I also found configuring callouts is very time consuming. My app got much faster when I replaced official callouts with a custom view that is only configured after a tap. ( I didn't do this for performance reasons but it had this positive side effect)